# EclipseLink Moxy with Java11

Tags: eclipselink, moxy, java-11

I asked this questions already here:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1098133/

Now, after 3 weeks, i hope to have luck to reach a response here in stackoverflow.

I have a RCP applcation using MOXy to parse complex XML, the annotated classes are generated by XJC, and the package contains a ObjectFactory and a jaxb.properties pointing to MOXy.

**The problem:** The application works with Java8, but starting the application with Java11, i get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50000] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: The context path mypackage contains no ObjectFactory or jaxb.index, no external metadata was found in properties Map, and sessions.xml was found or was invalid.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7095] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException

Exception Description: The sessions.xml resource [sessions.xml] was not found on the resource path.  Check that the resource name/path and classloader passed to the SessionManager.getSession are correct.  The sessions.xml should be included in the root of the application's deployed jar, if the sessions.xml is deployed in a sub-directory in the application's jar ensure that the correct resource path using "/" not "\" is used.]
```

My target platform contains:

- org.eclipse.persistence.moxy_2.7.4....jar
- jaxb-osgi-2.3.2.jar
- jakarta.activation.jar
- jakarta.xml.bind-api.jar

I use Multi-Release: true to be able to handle Java8 vs. Java9+.
In the main MANIFEST.FM i require org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.
In the versions/9/OSGI-INF/MANIFEST.FM I add the import packages: com.sun.xml.bind.v2, javax.xml.bind

To start the application in the Eclipse run configuration dialog, i switch the JRE Java8 vs Java11, and in the plugins tab, i remove (J8) or add (J11) com.sun.xml.bind.jaxb-osgi (jaxb-osgi.jar) to make it startable.

Can someone help?

regards
Frank

Comment: I'm running into a similar "no ObjectFactory or jaxb.index" message. In my case I think it's a class loader problem. The class loader for the jakarta plug-in can't access the *jaxb.index* files that exist, but are loaded by sibling class loaders for other plug-ins. **If you found a solution, it would be okay to answer your own question, and I would appreciate it.**